# selenium xpath scrape of mixed content html span

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to scrape a span element that has mixed content

```
<span id="span-id">
  <!--starts with some whitespace-->
  <b>bold title</b>
  <br/>
  text here that I want to grab....
</span>
```

And here's a code snippet of a grab that identifies the span.  It picks it up without a problem but the text field of the webelement is blank.

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://page-to-examine.com");
var query = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='span-id']"));
```

I've tried adding /text() to the expression which also returns nothing.  If I add /b I do get the text content of the bolded text - which happens to be a title that I'm not interested in.

I'm sure with a bit of xpath magic this should be easy but I'm not finding it so far!!  Or is there a better way?  Any comments gratefully received.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and for three alternative XPath expressions, each of which selects exactly the wanted text node. XSLT-based verification is also provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried adding `/text()` to the expression which also returns nothing

This selects *all* the text-node-children of the context node -- and there are three of them.

What you refer to "nothing" is most probably the first of these, which is a white-space-only text node (thus you see "nothing" in it).

**What you need is**:

```
//span[@id='span-id']/text()[3]
```

**Of course, there are other variations possible**:

```
//span[@id='span-id']/text()[last()]
```

Or:

```
//span[@id='span-id']/br/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     "<xsl:copy-of select="//span[@id='span-id']/text()[3]"/>"
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This transformation simply outputs whatever the XPath expression selects. When applied on the provided XML document** (comment removed):

```
<span id="span-id">
    <b>bold title</b>
    <br/>
    text here that I want to grab....   
</span>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
     "
    text here that I want to grab....   
"
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre.  I've tried all of these using an xml/xsl files and all work a treat.  Interestingly, Selenium does not work when using any of these :( but I did find, and this is a hack I know, but using //span[@id='span-id']/b/.. does work populating the webelement.text of the span (admittedly all the text under the span is returned but I can work with that!)  Thanks again.

Comment: @SGB: You are welcome. I's a pity Selenium isn't fully compliant as an XPath processor -- I'll remember your trick.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following xpath query should work for your case. following-sibling useful for what you're trying to do.

```
//span[@id='span-id']/br/following-sibling::text()
```